# Docker Quickstart: Failed to contact an active Resource Manager: Hue Failed

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, hue

I've installed CDH on macbook and installation seemed to go well without any errors.

1. Now when I run it, I see one failed item in console LOGS:
   Starting hue: G[FAILED]
2. And Hue QuickStart page (localhost:8888) tell about misconfiguration:

```
Checking current configuration
Configuration files located in /etc/hue/conf.empty
Potential misconfiguration detected. Fix and restart Hue.
Resource Manager    Failed to contact an active Resource Manager: ('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))
Hive    
The application won't work without a running HiveServer2.

Checking Logs: (Related Snippets)
Started Hive Server2 (hive-server2):G[  OK  ]
resourcemanager running as process 961. Stop it first.
Started Hadoop resourcemanager:G[  OK  ]
Starting hue: G[FAILED]
```

Comment: Please add some more information on your installation (and configuration) so the problem becomes more transparent.

Comment: @FabianSchöner **System Configuration**: Mac book **8GB** Ram and i5(**4 core**) processor. I've assigned Docker image **4GB** ram and **2 core** CPU. For installation i used default automated process: **docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -t -i [OPTIONS] [IMAGE] /usr/bin/docker-quickstart**

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue resolved by increasing assigned CPU and RAM to 3 and 6 respectively.

Though i still keep on getting: Starting hue: G[FAILED], but i'm able to open Hue page and operate it.